# Finding the general solution for complex trig equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

- $4\tan^2 x-3=0$

---

- $ \tan^2 x =\frac34$
- $x = \tan^{-1}(\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$)

therefore general solution

$x= \tan^{-1}(\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) + n\pi$ where $n$ is an element of all real numbers.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: sorry , i wanted someone to confirm/validate the method.

Comment: There are two errors in the conclusive sentence.

Comment: which part... :/

Comment: Did you want to say $n$ is an element of all integer numbers?

Comment: i fixed it, and isn't it just real? The symbol n is an element of Z (I forgot what this stands for)

Comment: Can $n$ take any real value ?

Comment: Maybe the OP meant by "complex" the word difficult, in stead of the complex numbers ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basics:** The set of solutions to the equation $\tan x=a$ is given by $$\left\{
\tan^{-1}(a)+n\pi\;\left|\right.\; n\in\mathbb Z
\right\}.$$
So in your particular example: $$\eqalign{
4\tan^2 x-3=0 & \iff \tan^2x=\dfrac34 \\ &\iff \tan x=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}2 \\ &\iff x=\tan^{-1}\left(\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}2\right)+n\pi.\qquad n\in\mathbb Z \\
}$$
So your error is that you considered $n$ to be a real number, but that's false, since then the set of solutions would have been the entire $\mathbb R$.

Comment: thank you! :) thats all i wanted to know

Comment: @confused Glad I could help. $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$